# Passing JSON from SignalR back to Knockout ViewModel

Tags: c#, json, knockout.js, signalr

I don't think I'm doing this properly, and I haven't really been able to figure out why. I'm new to Knockout and SignalR and just kind of putzing through it.

Currently, if I put a debug HTML element on my page and databind it to `dashboard` on the ViewModel, I get all of my JSON outputted.

Although, if I try to do any databinding, I get undefined errors. Like for instance I tried to do the following:

```
<div data-bind="with: dashboard">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Staff</th>
            <th>Certification</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Organization</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Requirement</th>
            <th>Requirement Type</th>
            <th>Start</th>
            <th>Term</th>
            <th>End</th>
        </tr>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: expiringRequirements">
            <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Certification"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I get an `undefined` error for `expiringRequirements` but I also get an undefined for `ExpiringRequirements` (which is actually what is spit back in my JSON).

Can anyone help and tell me what I'm doing wrong? As far as I can tell, the SignalR part is working perfectly.

Also, would it make more sense to move the individual observables into the ViewModel? Ideally if only one section changes I would target it directly, I feel like it's unnecessary putting them into a model.

### Models and ViewModels

```
var dashboardViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.hub = $.connection.dashboardHub;
    self.expiringRequirements = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.completedNotes = ko.observable();
    self.newUsers = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.reportables = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.init = function (portalId) {
        self.hub.server.fetchDataReportingItemsAsync(portalId);
    }

    self.updateEntireDashboard = function (result) {
        self.expiringRequirements(data.ExpiringRequirements);
        self.completedNotes(data.CompletedNotes);
        self.newUsers(data.NewUsers);
        self.reportables(data.Reportables);
    }
};

$(function () {
    var viewModel = new dashboardViewModel();
    var portalId = <%= PortalId %>

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    $.connection.hub.logging = true;

    hub = $.connection.dashboardHub;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        viewModel.init(portalId);
    });

    hub.client.upadateDashboardData = function (data) {
        viewModel.updateEntireDashboard(JSON.parse(data));
    }

    
});
```

**Edit**: Updated my viewmodel and removed the model since the pieces of the viewmodel will be separate anyway and can update independently. Makes more sense to flatten it out to me. However, binding it still not functional

### Hub

```
public async void FetchDataReportingItemsAsync(int portalId)
{
    PortalId = portalId;
    var getNewUsersTask = GetNewUsersAsync();
    var getReportablesTask = GetReportablesAsync();
    var getExpiringReqsTask = GetExpiringRequirementsAsync();
    //var getCompletedNotesTask = GetCompletedNotesAsync();
    
    //Ensure that this includes every awaitable task
    await Task.WhenAll(getNewUsersTask, getReportablesTask, getExpiringReqsTask);

    DashboardReportingViewModel vm = new DashboardReportingViewModel()
    {
        NewUsers = getNewUsersTask.Result,
        Reportables = getReportablesTask.Result,
        ExpiringRequirements = getExpiringReqsTask.Result
        //CompletedNotes = getCompletedNotesTask.Result
    };
    
    Clients.All.updateDashboardData(vm);
}
```

Comment: I think SignalR does not parse your JSON when calling `addDashbordData` so you need to do it manually with `hub.client.addDashboardData = function (data) {
        viewModel.addDashboardMessage(JSON.parse(data)); }`

Comment: Is there any reason to do the JSON serialize on the hub method then?

Comment: As far as I know SignalR can handle complex return types so you can just write: `Clients.All.addDashboardData(vm);` and on the client side you don't need to parse just write: `hub.client.addDashboardData = function (data) {         viewModel.addDashboardMessage(data); }`

Comment: I'll try that and see if it fixes my binding problems.

Comment: Well I didn't get any errors, but binding still is not working properly

Comment: I simplified my ViewModel and binding is still not working correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that I changed the parameter in my Viewmodel's `updateEntireDashboard` to result and didn't update `data.ExpiringRequirements` etc to `result.ExpiringRequirements`

Works as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `viewModel.dashboard(data);` it won't work because it would just replace the observables with the non observable properties in data, and if you use `viewModel.dashboard(new Dashboard(data));` it wont work either because it will actually create new observable that are different from the ones that the dom has been bound to. The best way I know to update a bunch of existing observables with new data is to use the knockout [mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin.

Comment: Here's another option besides the mapping plugin: http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html

Comment: Updating my question with some edits to the ViewModel I did to potentially simplify things

Answer (score 0):

I think your [with binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) is wrong:

```
<div data-bind="with: dashboard">
```

This makes `viewModel.dashboard` the [binding-context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) for all the rest of your data bindings.

Since `viewModel.dashboard` is undefined, it makes sense that you would get "undefined errors".